# question re: customHooks, setTimeout closure, and useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

So I have a component, and when it mounts I look at a "process status" value that is exposed to me via a custom hook (useStatus). If that status is "loading", then I start the process of polling an API by calling a function from another hook (useAPI). Each time I "poll", I am updating the redux state, and the idea is that when the value changes indicating that the status is "completed" I stop polling.

This is not working because the value I am using in the setTimeout closure is "stale". I think I understand that this is because when setTimeout is called, it's creating a closure, and that closure does not have access to "updated" state values.

What I don't understand is why, if that is the case, does the statusRef.current value get updated? Through logging and debugging I've determined that the original selector (that lives in the setTimeout closure) is called again when the state changes because of [this checkForUpdates function in the useSelector code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L58).

But I would have thought that the original call to useSelector would have returned a string (and not an object) that is stored on the statusRef.current property. And I can't understand how subsequent running of the selector would be able to "reassign" that value.

*Update*
I think the answer here is that useRef returns the same reference everytime, even on subsequent renders of the component. So the selector is running again, but that's probably not actually doing anything to my ref. But then the component re-renders, useRef gets called again, returns the same ref thats in the closure, and then the useSelector call (from the component rendering) happens again, writing the updated state value over the ref.

I've created a create-react-app project to demonstrate the behavior [here](https://github.com/dpistole/why-tho)

The code basically looks like this:

```
// App.js
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { status } = useStatus();
  const { pollForStatus } = useAPI();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(status === 'loading') {
      pollForStatus();
    }
  }, [pollForStatus, status]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div>
      Status is <span>{status}</span>.
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(({
            type: "SET_STATUS",
            status: "completed",
          }))
        }}>
        Click to update status.
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}



// useStatus.js
export default () => {
  const statusRef = useRef();
  statusRef.current = useSelector(state => state.status);

  return {
    status: statusRef.current,
    statusRef,
  };
}


// useAPI.js
export default () => {
  const { status, statusRef, } = useStatus();
  const pollForStatus = async () => {
    const poll = async (resolve, reject) => {
      await apiRequestThatUpdatesState();
      // here `status` is the same value is was when the setTimeout closure was created
      // but `statusRef.current changes to the "updated value" eventually
      if (status === 'loading') {
        setTimeout(poll, 5000, resolve, reject);
      }
    }
    return new Promise(poll);
  };

  return {
    pollForStatus,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer here is that useRef returns the *same* reference everytime, even on subsequent renders of the component. So the selector is running again, but that's probably not actually doing anything to my ref. But then the component re-renders, useRef gets called again, returns the *same* ref thats in the closure, and then the useSelector call (from the component rendering) happens again, writing the updated state value over the ref.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick review, the code itself in useAPI has an infinite loop that needs to fix.
Coming back to the question, the useEffect must initiate a listening worker so it can update status. it would be something like below

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await apollForStatus();
      setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [pollForStatus, status]);
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. The react-redux code does have a a subscription to state events that seems to run my selector again when the state changes (the checkForUpdates function mentioned in the OP). But I don't understand how running the selector again changes the variable `statusRef.current`. In the redux code it assigns the value to `latestSelectedState.current`, but I don't see anything in the code where it ever assigned `lastSelectedState.current` to `statusRef.current`, and I'm trying to understand how that all happens.

Comment: I suppose its possible that subsequent  renders of the component (that occur as a result of the state changes), call useStatus() again. Maybe this ends up updating the _same_ ref that is used in the closure. I had thought each time useStatus, (and then useRef) was called it would be creating a new ref, but maybe I'm incorrect there.